# What / where are the required libraries for JSF (specifically javax.faces stuff)

Tags: java, jsf, resources

I've spent the last several hours searching the web, and I can't figure this one out.

I want to include some `javax.faces` classes in a java package I'm working on.

Specifically:

```
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.VariableResolver;
```

I'm using eclipse 3.4

I know how to include external libraries, set up my build path etc.

What I do NOT know is what libraries (jars, libs, whatever) contain classes I need, nor do I know where to find them.  I know the information is out there (people are developing JSF stuff all over the word), but I seem incapable of figuring this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using myfaces then you need myfaces-api.jar and myfaces-impl.jar in your classpath, which you can download from http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those packages come from Java EE version 5 (it's documented in its javadocs, along with things like Servlet API). And as such it's usually provided by your app/servlet container; Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish etc -- as long as container supports Java EE 5.

Comment: @StaxMan - Tomcat and Jetty do not implement the JEE spec and do not include a JSF implementation. Glassfish is a JEE server.